# Android - getLayoutParams.height = -1?

Tags: android

I try to get a FrameLayout's height in onGlobalLayout(), this piece of code is in the onCreate() method:

```
final FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.detail_frame);
        ViewTreeObserver vto = layout.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener (this);

                ViewGroup.LayoutParams lPF = layout.getLayoutParams();

                int gg = layout.getHeight();
                int hh = lPF.height;
        }
    });
```

The XML file:

```
<FrameLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/detail_frame">
...
...
</FrameLayout>
```

but when I was debugging, 'gg' got the right height value, 'hh' got -1. I'm doing this because I want to set the layout's height. How can I get the right value of LayoutParams?

Comment: That is the "right" value. It corresponds to `MATCH_PARENT`, which means "make this the same as the parent's height, whatever that may be". The actual value won't be known until layout, at which point you can use `getHeight()`, like you have. The `LayoutParams#height` field won't be changed to reflect that value, though. It will remain at `MATCH_PARENT`. You can set exact values for that yourself, however, if that's what you mean to do.

Comment: @Mike M. Anyway to know if it's finished laying out?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. That's what you're already doing with the `OnGlobalLayoutListener`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Anyway to know if it's finished laying out?

You already did, `onGlobalLayout` is called when the view finishes laying out, that's why `getHeight` return non-zero pixel in height. If it's not drawn yet, `getHeight` will return 0

> How can I get the right value of LayoutParams?

Nothing is wrong here, it's a right value. You get -1 from `LayoutParams.height` because it's `MATCH_PARENT` placeholder value, just like `WRAP_CONTENT` = -2. Android read this layout params value, then calculate the real size in pixel, which will be the value you get when calling `getHeight`.

> I'm doing this because I want to set the layout's height

Just set the height value to the `LayoutParams`: `layout.getLayoutParams().height = 100`